# css gradient to ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer

How do I translate this to ie?

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #f7f7f7 1px, #FFFFFF 25px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#f7f7f7');
```

For additional properties of DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: There's no way to set any of the finer properties?

Comment: Other then [the msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(v=vs.85).aspx)? AFAIK not, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: This is true, it's the only CSS appliable gradient available on IE. You can't set any finer properties.